# Large scale human migrations from jungles

Tags: humans

Would that make sense? The jungle region I have is probably the 2nd or 3rd largest region in this world I'm building and I plan there being a large-scale migration event from this region. The reason for this migration event would be based off the nomadic migration domino effect I learned recently. What I would like to know is do jungle regions make good platforms for migrations? Would populations be sufficient enough on a global scale? Are there any examples of this in the real world?

Comment: The Bantu-speaking people were (and they still are) agriculturalists. They didn't (and still don't) live in the jungle. Think of them as the African equivalent of the Germanic or Slavic peoples of early-medieval European history. (And by and large the jungle supports only a reduced human population, for the reason that there isn't all that much to eat in a jungle. Hunter-gatherers populations are by necessity much sparser than agricultural populations.)

Comment: Over the past four thousand years, the human migrations have nearly all come from grasslands and other agricultural areas. The Indo-Europeans started by getting the mutation that allowed them to digest horse milk past infancy. That gave them the population growth to start migrating to other areas. Europe has had wave after wave of migrations from the grasslands of central Asia.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke the domino effect, that means someone else is moving into the jungle while the people in question are moving / being driven out.  With nomads on the Asian Steppe it was groups of culturally different people with similar lifestyles.  I suspect similar things happened with the Plains Indians.

In the real world, Pygmies are people who live / lived in a jungle.  They are being driven out of their traditional lands but not by people who live like them.  They are being driven out by agriculturalist moderns seeking to exploit the jungle either for its resources or as a base for military operations.

[A Pygmy traveller gives voice to a marginalized people](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/12/01/world/africa/01lonoa.html)

> While most Pygmies still live in the forest, they are being displaced
> and driven out by the relentless encroachment of the modern world:
> huge logging enterprises, settlement, the development of national
> parks, and violence among militias and rebel groups. Forced to
> relinquish their traditional territory — “land which we have occupied
> forever,” Mr. Lonoa said — and lacking both civil documentation and a
> political voice, Pygmies often take up a precarious existence at the
> shabby margins of society.

You could definitely have jungle peoples move out because other peoples are moving in and displacing them.

Answer (score 1):

**Look to examples from South America**

The Mayan culture went through a boom bust cycles in tropical/jungle environments. This lead to extensive cities developing, growing over a century or so and then suddenly being abandoned quite quickly, only for the Mayans to reestablish themselves and begin again. For a long time archeologists argued over what caused this e.g war, plague etc. However unless I'm in error a few years ago the issue was resolved.

Like all great cities the Mayans were reliant on agriculture to support growing populations. As their cities increased in size food surpluses became harder to maintain. Research indicates that about the time the cities were abandoned the Mayan were hit by a series of bad rainy seasons and crop failures. One or two? perhaps they may have managed by trading with other cities in the Empire. Four or five? No. The result was starvation civil war and mass migration away from the old cities. Only for them to start up again elsewhere.  (Prepared to be proven wrong about all of the above BTW - it is from memory.)

So depending on the geography/layout of you world you could have a domino effect of mass migration started by a collapsing tropical empire. I suggest reading up on the Maya to get more details and then adapting what you've learned to your setting.